# Cannot load external library in Amplify lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm totally new with these AWS stuff. I'm trying to establish a jdbc connection in my lambda function with my local database.  This my my gradle file config

```
apply plugin: 'java'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.15.0')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:2.2.7'
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.3'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'
}

jar.baseName = 'latest_build'

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
    archiveFileName = 'latest_build.zip'
}

build.dependsOn buildZip
```

This is my handler

```
public class LambdaRequestHandler implements RequestHandler<RequestClass, ResponseClass>{

public ResponseClass handleRequest(RequestClass request, Context context){
    String greetingString = String.format("Hello %s %s!", request.firstName, request.lastName);
    
    Connection con = null;

    String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "123456";

    try {
        Class.forName("org.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, username, password);
        System.out.println("connection created");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseClass(greetingString);
  }
}
```

Whenever I run **amplify mock function**, I always get **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver**
It seems that my code never reaches the connection Jar files, but these files are shown in my build zip folder. Is there anyway I can load these files only on my local device?